# Разбиение на блоки по битам

Tags: c++, криптография, union, байты

Занимаюсь реализацией алгоритма ГОСТ 28147-89.
Например, есть ключ 256 бит:

```
uint8_t key[32] = {
        1, 48, 48, 22, 48, 48, 48, 48,
        48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48,
        48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48,
        48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48,
};
```

Мне необходимо разбить его на блоки по 32 бита.
Есть такая функция:

```
void split(uint8_t *source, uint32_t *dest) {
    uint8_t *p8 = source;
    for (uint32_t *p32 = dest; p32 < dest + 8; ++p32) {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            *p32 = (*p32 << 8) | p8[i];
        }
        p8 += 4;
    }
}
```

В процессе я подумал, что ее можно упразднить и просто воспользоваться `union`

```
union {
    uint8_t  u8Key[32];
    uint32_t u32Key[8];
} UGKey;
```

В моей задумке я просто сходу мог бы обращаться к нужным мне парам байтов, вместо отдельного разбиения.

Но на выходе я получаю разные результаты:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    std::cout << k32[i] << " " << k32t[i] << std::endl;
}
```

---

Левый столбец получен с помощью `union`, а правый с помощью функции `split`.

```
372256769 19935254
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
808464432 808464432
```

Возможно ли вообще через union добиться подобного результата или я пытаюсь сделать ерунду ?

Comment: Как сказал VTT, в C++ подобный код (type punning) вызывает UB, однако в C — нет. В C такое поведение определяется реализацией. А вообще, дело в разном порядке байтов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, если в `union` сначала заполнить поле `u8Key`, а затем обратится к полю `u32Key`, то будет неопределенное поведение. В `union` в любой момент времени может быть активно не более одного поля, и использовать его для кастования между этими полями нельзя.